# How to make a simple menu navigation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not really satisfied with what I can find. I just want a simple example of a menu system in Angularjs with hover effect and selection effect.

I understand that 'hover' effects can be done in CSS, but this is more of an exercise for me to understand angularjs better.

What I am trying to do is pretty basic stuff.

Basically I have some HTML which has some DIVs (or menu items) :

```
<div NavCtrl id="header">
    <div class="item" ng-click="click(1)" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
1
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-click="click(2)" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
2
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-click="click(3)" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
3
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to do two things.

- listen on **click**
- listen on **mouseIn** and **mouseOut**

I understand..

1. It is probably nicer to do the hover effect in CSS
2. It is possible to do some inline logic in the HTML with angularjs

...because I want to have flow on effects from these events. A hover event needs to pull information out related to that menu item, and a click event should also be able to perform some action related to that menu item. Cheap CSS tricks are not going to solve this!

For my hover logic, I thought this would do the trick :

```
  $scope.hoverIn = function($event){
    angular.element($event.srcElement).addClass('hover')
  };

  $scope.hoverOut = function($event){
    angular.element($event.srcElement).removeClass('hover')
  };
```

However $event is undefined :( . How do I get to the element object from a mouseover event?

My click logic looks like this :

```
  $scope.click = function(position, $event) {

    elem = angular.element($event.srcElement);

    if (elem.hasClass("clicked")) {
      elem.removeClass("clicked")
    }else {
      elem.addClass("clicked")
    }

    // if (position == 1) //do something etc...
  };
```

Same problem : $event is undefined. I also want to pass in the index, so that I can do something special for certain menu items.

My Fiddle is here :

https://jsfiddle.net/zxjg3tpo/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularjs you can get the event by using [$event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) in your html code

```
<div class="item" ng-click="click(1,$event)" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)">
```

Hover Logic

```
 $scope.hoverIn = function($event){
    angular.element($event.target).addClass('hover')
  };

  $scope.hoverOut = function($event){
    angular.element($event.target).removeClass('hover')
  };
```

Click logic

```
$scope.click = function(position, $event) {

    elem = angular.element($event.target);

    if (elem.hasClass("clicked")) {
      elem.removeClass("clicked")
    }else {
      elem.addClass("clicked")
    }

    // if (position == 1) //do something etc...
  };
```

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zxjg3tpo/6/

Here is another updated Fiddle where the siblings have their class removed (to make the click  work correct)
https://jsfiddle.net/zxjg3tpo/9/

Comment: ahhh it's 'target' not 'srcElement'. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)"
```

How it works: ng-mouseenter is kinda clever and it has $event in its scope in addition to what you have (i.e. you have hoverIn). So when it parse provided expression, it launches hoverIn with event.

All work with elements, like addClass should be done in directives where you have direct access to html element. Sometimes you may need `angular.element(...)` but in most cases you are happy with current element. (In directive link : function(scope, element, attrs))

Answer (score 1):

You missed to pass *$event* from html and the *srcElement* was wrong.
Please try the following:

**HTML**

```
    <body ng-app="navTest" ng-controller="NavTestCtrl">
<div id="header">
    <div class="item" ng-click="click(1, $event)" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)">
1
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-click="click(2, $event)" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)">
2
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-click="click(3, $event)" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)">
3
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('navTest', [

]);

app.controller('NavTestCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http) {

  $scope.click = function(position, $event) {

    elem = angular.element($event.target);

    if (elem.hasClass("clicked")) {
      elem.removeClass("clicked")
    }else {
      elem.addClass("clicked")
    }

    // if (position == 1) //do something etc...


  };


  $scope.hoverIn = function($event){
    angular.element($event.target).addClass('hover')
  };

  $scope.hoverOut = function($event){
    angular.element($event.target).removeClass('hover')
  };
});
```